# Hyperterminal is giving me JavaScript error code 267 When opening new tab

Tags: bash, git, hyperterminal

I have a hyperterminal, in which I used bash as the shell, like this...

```
    shell: 'C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe',
```

When I try to open a new tab on hyper terminal, I get an error with code 267. But when i use the default windows shell, The error does not appear. How do i fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was actually an easy fix, I hope it help somebody one day.

I removed the hypercwd plugin from the plugins in the hyper.js file

Comment: Hi! It's ok now. Windows 10. Thank you! ;)

Comment: Was exactly that, worked perfectly for me

Comment: 100% couldn't work it out saved me loads of time!

Comment: I don't have hypercwd.

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = {
```

config: {
// default font size in pixels for all tabs
fontSize: 12,

```
// font family with optional fallbacks
fontFamily: 'Menlo, "DejaVu Sans Mono", Consolas, "Lucida Console", monospace',

// terminal cursor background color and opacity (hex, rgb, hsl, hsv, hwb or cmyk)
cursorColor: 'rgba(248,28,229,0.8)',

// `BEAM` for |, `UNDERLINE` for _, `BLOCK` for █
cursorShape: 'BLOCK',

// color of the text
foregroundColor: '#fff',

// terminal background color
backgroundColor: '#000',

// border color (window, tabs)
borderColor: '#333',

// custom css to embed in the main window
css: '',

// custom css to embed in the terminal window
termCSS: '',

// set to `true` (without backticks) if you're using a Linux setup that doesn't show native menus
// default: `false` on Linux, `true` on Windows (ignored on macOS)
showHamburgerMenu: '',

// set to `false` if you want to hide the minimize, maximize and close buttons
// additionally, set to `'left'` if you want them on the left, like in Ubuntu
// default: `true` on windows and Linux (ignored on macOS)
showWindowControls: '',

// custom padding (css format, i.e.: `top right bottom left`)
padding: '12px 14px',

// the full list. if you're going to provide the full color palette,
// including the 6 x 6 color cubes and the grayscale map, just provide
// an array here instead of a color map object
colors: {
  black: '#000000',
  red: '#ff0000',
  green: '#33ff00',
  yellow: '#ffff00',
  blue: '#0066ff',
  magenta: '#cc00ff',
  cyan: '#00ffff',
  white: '#d0d0d0',
  lightBlack: '#808080',
  lightRed: '#ff0000',
  lightGreen: '#33ff00',
  lightYellow: '#ffff00',
  lightBlue: '#0066ff',
  lightMagenta: '#cc00ff',
  lightCyan: '#00ffff',
  lightWhite: '#ffffff'
},

// the shell to run when spawning a new session (i.e. /usr/local/bin/fish)
// if left empty, your system's login shell will be used by default
// make sure to use a full path if the binary name doesn't work
// (e.g `C:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe` instad of just `bash.exe`)
// if you're using powershell, make sure to remove the `--login` below
shell: 'C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-cmd.exe',

// for setting shell arguments (i.e. for using interactive shellArgs: ['-i'])
// by default ['--login'] will be used
shellArgs: ['--command=usr/bin/bash.exe', '-l', '-i'],

// for environment variables
env: { TERM: 'cygwin'},

// set to false for no bell
bell: 'SOUND',

// if true, selected text will automatically be copied to the clipboard
copyOnSelect: false

// if true, on right click selected text will be copied or pasted if no
// selection is present (true by default on Windows)
// quickEdit: true

// URL to custom bell
// bellSoundURL: 'http://example.com/bell.mp3',

// for advanced config flags please refer to https://hyper.is/#cfg
```

},

// a list of plugins to fetch and install from npm
// format: [@org/]project[#version]
// examples:
//   `hyperpower`
//   `@company/project`
//   `project#1.0.1`
plugins: [],

// in development, you can create a directory under
// `~/.hyper_plugins/local/` and include it here
// to load it and avoid it being `npm install`ed
localPlugins: []
};

empty the hyper.js file and paste this. it'll most probably work

Answer (score 0):

i got similar type of error when i configured the hyper config for using git bash but in my case the git location was on another drive so i changed the location in the preferences file inside shell line but it didn't work but in a weird way when i changed the location's path from '\' to '/' it worked.